90s or early 00s movie where teenagers get superpowers
I'm looking for a movie where teenagers get superpowers. I'm pretty sure it's an older movie from probably the early 2000's or the 1990's. There's a scene where a boy from the group uses his power to humiliate either his teacher or another student in his class. One of them also has telekinesis and she used it to do a open handed palm uppercut to the nose, and when she did it, it came out like a hand but orange.  
I doubt it's a lighthearted movie, it's pretty dark. I remember the ending involves the antagonist in a wheelchair and someone brings her flowers. Please help me, I've been stuck on this for a while now.

"Early 2000 1990" is rather confusing. Can you edit the question to fix this? And I'm not sure what is meant by the telekinesis palm uppercut thing.

She had telekinesis and she used it to do a open handed palm uppercut to the nose. And when she did it it came out like a hand but orange.

Could it be "Sky High"  from 2005 with Kurt Russell???

No. I just thought about it and I doubt it's a light hearted movie like that it's a pretty dark movie. I remember the ending scene involves the antagonist in a wheelchair and someone brings her flowers.

Does this movie involve four teenagers with superpowers? One guy can heal, the girl manipulates people, the other guy can read minds, and the 2nd girl has telekinetic powers as well? If so, the movie is called The Source:

Four outcast teenagers acquire mystical powers that allow them to become gods on campus, with deadly consequences.


sorry it goes by "the source" in the UK and "the surge" in the U.S.

Omg thank you that's it it took me forever to find this movie.

I'm not very certain about that Orange palm uppercut thing (don't remember that particular detail) but from the brief description that you mentioned regarding pre 2000 era and other minor details, it seems like the movie "Matilda" (1996). You may just take a watch and see if that's what you've been looking for. Right one or not, just share in your reply buddy.

Not trying to be rude but the only thing that can be associated with Matilda from my question is the 1990's sentence. I know for a fact that's not the right movie.
